# Moshi adapter creation failure: "requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered"

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

```
 var wall= ArrayList<VKWall>()
    try {
         val response = r.getString("response") as String
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
        val type: Type = Types.newParameterizedType(
            ArrayList::class.java,
            VKWall::class.java
        )
        val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<ArrayList<VKWall>> = moshi.adapter(type)

        wall = jsonAdapter.fromJson(response)!!

    } catch (e: JSONException){}

    return wall
```

It can not create adapter. Debuger can`t execute this string and goes to exception of function over this code

```
val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<ArrayList<VKWall>> = moshi.adapter(type)
```

I`am trying to do everything like there
https://github.com/square/moshi

```
Platform java.util.ArrayList<com.e.app.fragments.vk_tabs.WallFragment.DataPackage.VKWall> (with no annotations) requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered


@Parcelize
@JsonClass(



   generateAdapter = true)
    data class VKWall (
      //  val UserName:String="",
       // val UserSurname:String="",
        @Json(name = "text")
        val Text:String="" ,
      //  val attachments: Attachments?,
      //  val copyright: String="",
      //  val repost: Repost? 
    ):Parcelable
    {


    }
```

Comment: can you add the exception ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in that moshi don't have adapter for yours class VKWall. To resolve this you could add `KotlinJsonAdapterFactory` that based on reflection:

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    // ... add your own JsonAdapters and factories ...
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()
```

Or you could use generated adapter like this:

```
// Annotate yours class @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class VKWall(
 ....
)
```

More documentation about this https://github.com/square/moshi#kotlin

More about yours problem https://www.zacsweers.dev/a-closer-look-at-moshi-1-9/

> Now, for Kotlin classes, you either need to use code gen,
>   KotlinJsonAdapterFactory, or supply your own custom JsonAdapter.
>   This is a potentially dangerous change! In projects using code gen,
>   there are cases where Kotlin classes could have (appeared to) Just
>   Work™️ before if you forgot to annotate them with @JsonClass. These
>   will fail at runtime now. If you're worried about this, I suggest
>   using Moshi 1.9 only in debug builds for a period of time to tease
>   these out before releasing production builds with it.

Comment: It strange, because I did it   @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)

Comment: Do you also add `kapt("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.9.2")`?

Comment: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution

Comment: Could you please add VKWall code to yours question? Try to `clean/rebuild` project. If all works correctly you could see generated adapter `VKWallJsonAdapter` at `build` folder. Or you can try KotlinJsonAdapterFactory

Comment: rebuilding project does not change anything. KotlinJsonAdapterFactory it can not find. Looks like I must write it by myself?

Comment: To use KotlinJsonAdapterFactory you should add additional dependency  `implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.9.2")`

Comment: I would like to, but with this projects build crassing with message A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution

Comment: ou! I changed version of moshi. Builded. No. It does not work. I mean. Building of project failed wit same message

Comment: I think, what a have to add gradle?

Comment: At first it should be `implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.9.2")`
If you want use codegen `kapt("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.9.2")` (https://github.com/square/moshi#codegen) If you want use kotlin-reflection `implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.9.2")` (https://github.com/square/moshi#reflection)

Comment: def moshi_version = '1.9.2'
    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.9.2")
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshi_version"
    kapt("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.9.2")     It`s looks like all aded

Comment: I think what better forget about moshi